# Update the relation to point at settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL

Tags: python, django, facebook, django-models, django-facebook

I'm getting this error. I'm trying to configure tschellenbach/Django-facebook package. I was getting "user or profile didnt have attribute facebook_id" error. So I tried to configure it using the code from [facebook_example](https://github.com/tschellenbach/Django-facebook/tree/master/facebook_example) which is a working example provided with the package. What should I do to sort it ? Please help

```
course.course: 'author' defines a relation with the model 'auth.User',
which has been swapped out. Update the relation to point at 
settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL.
```

My models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
import datetime 
from django.utils import timezone
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify
from django.db.models.signals import post_save # new added
from django.conf import settings # new added
from django.dispatch import receiver # new added

from django_facebook.utils import get_profile_model # new added
from django_facebook.models import FacebookModel, get_user_model # new added
import logging # new added
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
from django_facebook.models import FacebookProfileModel
from django.contrib.auth import models as auth_models


#______________________facebook model start_________________________________
                                                                            #
try:                                                                        # 
    from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser, UserManager        #
    class CustomFacebookUser(AbstractUser, FacebookModel):                  #
        objects = UserManager()                                             # 
        state = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)     # 
except ImportError, e:                                                      #
    logger.info('Couldnt setup FacebookUser, got error %s', e)              #
    pass                                                                    #

auth_models.CustomFacebookUser = CustomFacebookUser

                                                                    #
class UserProfile(FacebookModel):                                           #
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)                   #  
                                                                            # 
    @receiver(post_save)                                                        #
    def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):                    #
        if sender == get_user_model():                                          #
            user = instance                                                     #
            profile_model = get_profile_model()                                 #  
            if profile_model == UserProfile and created:                        #
                profile, new = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=instance) #
                                                                            # 
#______________________facebook model end __________________________________#


class PostManager(models.Manager):
    def live(self):
        return self.model.objects.filter(published=True)



class Course(models.Model):
    course_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, blank=True, default='')
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published',default=timezone.now())
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="courses")
    published_course = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    objects = PostManager()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-pub_date", "course_name"]

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.course_name

    def was_published_recently(self):
        now = timezone.now()
        return now - datetime.timedelta(days=1) <= self.pub_date < now

    was_published_recently.admin_order_field = 'pub_date'
    was_published_recently.boolean = True
    was_published_recently.short_description = 'Published recently ?'   

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify(self.course_name)
        super(Course, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    @models.permalink   
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ("course:detail", (), {"slug": self.slug})


class Content(models.Model):
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course)
    topic_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug_topic_name = models.SlugField(max_length=200, blank=True, default='')
    desc = models.TextField()
    published = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    objects = PostManager()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.topic_name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug_topic_name:
            self.slug_topic_name = slugify(self.topic_name)
        super(Content, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    @models.permalink   
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ("content:detail", (), {"slug_topic_name": self.slug_topic_name})
```

My settings/base.py or settings file

```
# Django settings for sai project.
import os
import django

import dj_database_url
# here() gives us file paths from the root of the system to the directory
# holding the current file.
here = lambda * x: os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), *x)

PROJECT_ROOT = here("..")
# root() gives us file paths from the root of the system to whatever
# folder(s) we pass it starting at the parent directory of the current file.
root = lambda * x: os.path.join(os.path.abspath(PROJECT_ROOT), *x)

DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ADMINS = (
    # ('Your Name', 'your_email@example.com'),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

DATABASES = {
    'default': dj_database_url.config()
}

SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
# Hosts/domain names that are valid for this site; required if DEBUG is False
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['http://glacial-waters-9009.herokuapp.com']

# Local time zone for this installation. Choices can be found here:
# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name
# although not all choices may be available on all operating systems.
# In a Windows environment this must be set to your system time zone.
TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Calcutta'

# Language code for this installation. All choices can be found here:
# http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

SITE_ID = 1

# If you set this to False, Django will make some optimizations so as not
# to load the internationalization machinery.
USE_I18N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not format dates, numbers and
# calendars according to the current locale.
USE_L10N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not use timezone-aware datetimes.
USE_TZ = True

# Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.
# Example: "/var/www/example.com/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = root("..", "..", "uploads")

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://example.com/media/", "http://media.example.com/"
MEDIA_URL = ''

# Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
# Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
# in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
# Example: "/var/www/example.com/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = root("..", "..", "static")

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://example.com/static/", "http://static.example.com/"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    root("..", "assets"),
)

# List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
# various locations.
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

# Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.
SECRET_KEY = '5gaq%we#w1strbini!-%5#p#a5644oe^2zr!ic3245ewhfm-^l_9*_fo'

# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'sai.urls'

# Python dotted path to the WSGI application used by Django's runserver.
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'sai.wsgi.application'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    root("templates"),
)

DJANGO_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.admin',
)

LOCAL_APPS = (
    'course',
)

THIRD_PARTY_APPS = (
    'south',
    'django_facebook',
)

INSTALLED_APPS = DJANGO_APPS + LOCAL_APPS + THIRD_PARTY_APPS

#__________________________Facebook settings Start___________________________

FACEBOOK_APP_ID = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' 
FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS =(
    "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
    "django.core.context_processors.debug",
    "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
    "django.core.context_processors.media",
    "django.core.context_processors.static",
    "django.core.context_processors.tz",
    "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    'django_facebook.context_processors.facebook',
)

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django_facebook.auth_backends.FacebookBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)

django_version = django.VERSION
# some complications related to our travis testing setup
DJANGO = os.environ.get('DJANGO', '1.5.1')
MODE = os.environ.get('MODE', 'standalone')
CUSTOM_USER_MODEL = bool(int(os.environ.get('CUSTOM_USER_MODEL', '1')))

if DJANGO != '1.5.1':
    CUSTOM_USER_MODEL = False

if CUSTOM_USER_MODEL:
    AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'django_facebook.FacebookCustomUser'
else:
    AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'auth.User' 
    AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'sai.UserProfile' 


#__________________________facebook settings End_____________________________

# A sample logging configuration. The only tangible logging
# performed by this configuration is to send an email to
# the site admins on every HTTP 500 error when DEBUG=False.
# See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging for
# more details on how to customize your logging configuration.
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that now you have got a `CUSTOM USER` and you are doing a   `ForeingKey` to the `Django User Model` ( `author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="courses"`)
) to get the new `User` you can do this at the beginning of any file where you will use `User`

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model as user_model
User = user_model()
```

Comment: I got this error when I migrate the app `IntegrityError: insert or update on table "course_course" violates foreign key constraint "author_id_refs_id_b
120d116"
DETAIL:  Key (author_id)=(1) is not present in table "django_facebook_facebookcustomuser".`

Comment: Thanks-a-lot it worked. Not getting errors anymore. Although when I login with facebook nothings gets added in facebook user column

Comment: I'm getting `models aren't loaded yet`

Comment: @ioanb7 Try posting another question and send us the link